# I can delete my QuickParts in Word 2013, how can I change that?

Tags: word, template, quick-parts

I have a Word template in my SharePoint library where people have to fill out a document and the information are filled in the library columns. Here my problem:

Some fields are mandatory. But the QuickParts are deleteable. That means if someone deletes a mandatory QuickPart per accident he cannot save the document anymore.

How can I change the setting so its not possible for users to delete them? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer is described:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother/why-are-my-quick-parts-deletable-and-how-can-i/29ee3b10-2a39-4c3a-82da-514563d0843c

1. Turn on the Developer Tab on Word
2. You can edit the properties there (restrict editing etc.)